# List of two attributes in same class

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Entity Class called `Session` and it containts two attributes:   `LecturerOne` and `LectureTwo`. I want to create a union of all the distinct names in `LecturerOne` and `LecturerTwo`:

I got just LecturerOne working.

```
public List<string> ListLecturer()
{
    var lecturerNames = (from s in db.Sessions                
                         select s.LecturerOne).Distinct();

    List<string> lecturerList = lecturerNames.ToList(); 
    return lecturerList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

```
var list = db.Sessions.SelectMany(s => new string[] { s.LecturerOne,
                                                      s.LecturerTwo })
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToList();
```

I don't know offhand how EF will treat that, but it's worth a try...

Alternatively, similar to Jamiec's answer but IMO simpler:

```
var list = db.Sessions.Select(s => s.LecturerOne)
                      .Union(db.Sessions.Select(s => s.LecturerTwo))
                      .ToList();
```

([`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156049.aspx) already returns distinct results, so there's no need to do it explicitly.)

Answer (score 2):

```
var lecturerOnes = (from s in db.Sessions                
                            select s.LecturerOne);
var lecturerTwos = (from s in db.Sessions                
                            select s.LecturerTwo);

List<string> lecturerList = lecturerOnes.Union(lectureTwos).ToList();
```